# Use another framework than persits for Mails

Tags: email, iis, asp-classic, smtp

I have to move some customer website from one (old) server to another (newer one). All sites are programmed in ASP. One customer sends Email (for his webshop) to his users using the persits framework, like

```
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
Mail.Host = "mail.domain.com"
Mail.CharSet = "ISO..."
Mail.Username = "Admin@domain.com"
Mail.Password = "password"
Mail.From = shopmail
Mail.FromName = "Name"
Mail.AddAddress shopmail
Mail.Subject = "Order " & date
Mail.Body = msgBody
Mail.Send
```

This framework isn't installed on the new server and also there are no SMTP services installed.

How could I get it done that mails could be sent without the features mentioned above? Is there a way to reach a external STMP server with ASP?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v found a solution, it's well documented [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/email/article.php/c19327/Sending-Email-Via-an-External-SMTP-Server-Using-CDO.htm) (for everyone who's interested in :) ).